# Getting attribute error while trying load multiple images from a directory using OpenCv

Tags: image-processing, python-3.6, opencv3.0

I am trying to load four images into my python file from a directory for further processing.

```
import cv2 as cv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import numpy as np
cv_img=[]
acne_string=[]
trust_score=[]


def avg(lst): 
    return sum(lst) / len(lst) 



for img in glob.glob("/home/centura/Desktop/Centura Tech/p1-Diseases/New_acne_grades/Transformed images/API-testing/images/*.jpg"):


    u = cv.imread(img, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
    smoothing=cv.GaussianBlur(u.copy(),(5,5),cv.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    img_grey = cv.cvtColor(smoothing.copy(), cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    plt.imshow(img_grey)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()
```

The python script basically does threshold and gray scale conversion.
The problem is i am getting an error like this.

```
File "/home/centura/Desktop/Centura Tech/p1-Diseases/All grades test/t_t.py", line 40, in engine
    u = cv.imread(img, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'imread'
```

I am using python3 and opencv 3.4.3. I have to use OpenCV for reading in images i cannot use `PIL`. Any work around

Comment: I just edited some of indent errors in your code. I can run your code normally. Could you provide some images?

Comment: @HaBom i found the fault, my code is about 400 lines in between the code i have accidentally assigned cv as another variable.So python read it with the new value instead of image.